# Upgrading things later

Tags: updates, ppa, official-repositories

I have installed a bunch of apps using debs and ubuntu standard repos. Is it possible that when I add a ppa of such an app at later time ubuntu will update my app.

Common examples are apps such as wine, google chrome, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you install something via the package management system (dpkg and apt), when you `apt upgrade` or `apt dist-upgrade` it will look at all your locally defined sources (PPAs, official repos, local caches, CDs etc) and attempt to install the latest version of all packages.

`apt upgrade` will only upgrade something if it doesn't require installing extra packages, or removing some. Only `apt dist-upgrade` (or the newer `apt full-upgrade`) will do that.

If you want to avoid that, [you can "pin" the package](https://askubuntu.com/q/18654/449) to avoid updates.

---

If you install it via another method (eg `sudo make install`), unless you've also installed it via package management (seriously not recommended), `dist- upgrade` will either overwrite or install alongside.

Things you install manually tend to go into `.../local/...` or `/opt/...` directories to avoid direct clashes but this can mean you have more than one version of something installed at once.

Answer (score 0):

If you have downloaded and installed an DEB from a PPA-Page and add the PPA later, your apps will be updated.